# How to turn the class definition to Vue 3 component definition with "tc39" decorators?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, javascript-decorators, typescript-5

The API purposed in [tc39/proposal-decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#classes) is pretty different with previous decorators API.
Although the [TypeScript 5 does not fully support the new API yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75911042/4818123), the deprecating of the previous API is the matter of time, so I'll develop with the newest API.

The answer to question [Into what we need to convert the TypeScript class using decorators to get the valid Vue component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71701178/into-what-we-need-to-convert-the-typescript-class-using-decorators-to-get-the-va) is actual for the old API, but now it is required to solve same problem with newest API.

The initial code is

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

/* [ Theory ] Overrides the eponymous type of "typescript/lib/lib.decorators.d.ts".
*  [ Reference ] https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#classes */
type ClassDecorator = (value: Function, context: {
  kind: "class";
  name: string | undefined;
  addInitializer: (initializer: () => void) => void;
}) => Function | void;


const VueComponentOptions: ClassDecorator = (targetClass: Function, context: ClassDecoratorContext): Function | void => {

  // TODO check for the kind === "class"

  const vueOptions: ComponentOptions = {
    methods: {},
    computed: {}
  };

  return defineComponent(vueOptions);

};
```

Currently, the usage

```
/* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909821/the-classdecorator-type-defined-in-tc39-proposal-decorators-is-not-applicabl */
/* @ts-ignore TS1270 TS decorators are not fully TC39-compatible yet. */
@VueComponentOptions
export default class ReactiveStateExperimentalSample {

}
```

causes the error

> ````
> ReactiveState-ExperimentalSample.vue?../../node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1!../../node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet%5B1%5D.rules%5B10%5D.use%5B0%5D:7
> Uncaught TypeError: Function expected
>     ... ```
> ````

The cause is

> If any other type of value besides a function is returned, an error
> will be thrown.
>
> https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#classes

Maybe I need to wrap the `defineComponent` to function?

```js
const VueComponentOptions: ClassDecorator = (targetClass: Function, context: ClassDecoratorContext): Function | void => {

  const vueOptions: ComponentOptions = {
    methods: {},
    computed: {}
  };

  return (): ReturnType<typeof defineComponent> => defineComponent(vueOptions);

};
```

This time, there are no the JavaScript runtime error, but the Vue will emit the warning:

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:170 [Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type:
> undefined (undefined)    at     at

and of course, the component will not be rendered.

What I need to do inside `VueComponentOptions` for the newest decorators API + Vue 3 case?

Please don' recommend the third-party libraries because this question is focused on implementation.

Comment: please make a MRE on stackblitz (i.e. a single component with pachage.json listing exact dependency versions (as there's class-dec@7 and @8, prop-dec, etc))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are trying to:

   - Reimplement a newer alternative of vue-class-component: a class that returns `ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>`, with tc39 decorators

Please correct me if I understood incorrectly.

---

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { ComponentOptions, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import type { ComponentPublicInstance } from 'vue';

// vue\packages\runtime-core\src\component.ts
interface ClassComponent {
  new (...args: any[]): ComponentPublicInstance
  // here is where you put 
  __vccOpts: ComponentOptions
}

// you need a class saying it implements ComponentPublicInstance for this.$props and other acessors
const Base = class Base {} as any as ClassComponent;


@(function VueComponentOptions(cls) { // inplace to see implecit typings
  cls.__vccOpts = defineComponent({
    name: cls.name,
    // maybe like this or whatever way you want.
    // ClassComponent used a lot of tricks here.
    //   like co
    data: () => new cls(),
    props: ['msg'],
    // whatever else you need
  })
  // return undefined
})
export default class MyComponent extends Base {
  text = 'from class';
  fn() {
    this.text
    this.$props; // has acess to all things in ComponentPublicInstance 
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }} {{ text }}</h1>
</template>
```

See an implementation of alike thing for more info,
https://github.com/facing-dev/vue-facing-decorator/blob/master/src/index.ts#L29

---

If you want to be able to use both `@Ops class` and `@Ops({...etc}) class` you'll need an `(data: object) => ClassDecorator` overload

---

edit: I forgot about `__vccOpts`, here they are now

Comment: The you for the updated answer. "Please correct me ..." - It's close, however I want to change some API.  If we'll return the `defineComponent()`, the `Uncaught TypeError: Function expected` error will be thrown.

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD edited. ClassComponent uses `__vccOpts` static prop

Comment: Works fine now! Thank you for the supporting of your solution.